What boundary for Laplace's equation on a square gives the roughest interior?
Consider Laplace's_equation
on an $N \times N$ grid of squares with Dirichlet boundary conditions 
boundary $B \to$ interior $X,\  (4N - 4)$ boundary points $ \to (N-2)^2 $ interior points. 
As a measure of the roughness of a 2d surface $u( x, y )$, define
$\ roughness( u ) \equiv \ \| \nabla u \| $ .
What boundary $B$ for Laplace's equation on a grid of squares 
maximizes $\ roughness($ interior $X )$,
with the box constraint $\| B \|_{\infty} \leq 1$ ?

Since I'm miles away from a way to approach this, I ran a numerical experiment:

Starting with sin waves on the edges,
optimizations converge to square waves with opposite edges flipped.
But this is just an experiment.
(Is the problem any easier for the unit disk ? I'd accept an answer for that too.)
